# Can I process a file which is larger than the System memory with java memory-mapped-files (MappedByteBuffer)?

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

1. how does MappedByteBuffer work? When I creat a MappedByteBuffer object like this：

```
RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("./src/test.txt", "rw");
FileChannel Fcin = in.getChannel(); 
MappedByteBuffer mapBuff = Fcin.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 0xFFFF);
```

Does it means the MappedByteBuffer object hold all the content of this file?

2.If the answer to 1 is YES, how to explain this sentence in *Thinking in Java* (page 692)?

> Memory-mapped files allow you to create and modify files that are too
> big to bring into memory

3.What does it mean when the return value of isLoaded() is true to a MappedByteBuffer object?

Answer (score 1):

There are many question, but all are related so I shall try to answer them all:

> Can I process a file which is larger than the System memory with java memory-mapped-files (MappedByteBuffer)?

On decently recent OS that use virtual memory (in fact all current OS I know), the answer is *yes you can*

> how does MappedByteBuffer work?

It heavily depends on how the underlying OS handles memory mapped files. Most of the time, it declares a bunch of virtual memory mapped to the file content. That means the the `MappedByteBuffer` contains an image of the file data, but some pages may not be mapped to physical memory (ie: the actual data is only on the disk file)

> Does it means the MappedByteBuffer object hold all the content of this file?

Yes. At least virtually because the data could be loaded into memory *on demand*.

> If the answer to 1 is YES, how to explain this sentence in Thinking in Java...

Thanks to virtual memory, when you process a file larger than available memory, most of the data remains on disk. If you try to access data that is not currently mapped, the virtual memory system will (eventually discard some other memory pages and) map the pages containing the requested data into physical memory pages to (almost) transparently access that data.

> What does it mean when the return value of isLoaded() is true to a MappedByteBuffer object?

It is a hint that the whole content of the buffer is resident in physical memory. But the Javadoc makes clear that it is not a guarantee and that it is heavily OS dependant.

Long story made short, memory mapped files are a nice tool that allow to process a disk file as if is was a (possibly huge) byte array. The possible downside it that it easily allows to create programs with terrible performances, because the whole disk IO is hidden from the programmer, and it just look like when the system spends it time storing memory pages to disk and load them again. At the end, you may have a nice buffer looking like memory, but with disk IO access times.

My advice is that before using that, the programmer should wonder what will be the involved disk IO. In some use case, it will be faster than manually reading and processing a file because all accesses are guaranteed to be page aligned, on other ones it will be a disaster because non consecutive accesses will require tons of disk accesses.

Comment: Thank you! I'm surprised no one commented on or voted this as useful before.